# Firefox password autocomplete

Tags: firefox, passwords, autocomplete

i have a problem with Firefox autocomplete in login forms. When i enter a password and a username for the first time it asks me if i want to remember them, i click on "remember" and it saves the data, but when i log out and then return to the login page it shows me nothing. The password is autocompleted only after i enter the username. Is there a way to do the autocomplete immediately like in any other browser?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely what you're asking for, but I really [recommend using Lastpass for you password managing.](https://lastpass.com/)

Works great on Firefox AND Google Chrome and it will share you're passwords among browsers and computers

[Here's the extension link for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8542) and a feature overview:

> LastPass is the last password you will
>   ever need. It allows you to:
>
> - Create strong passwords, knowing you only have to remember one.
> - Automatically fill out forms to save you time
> - Log into your favorite sites with a single click
> - Access and manage your data from multiple computers seamlessly
> - Share logins with friends and let others share logins with you
> - Use One Time Passwords, and a Screen Keyboard to help keep you safe while
>     on the road.
> - Supports IE as well, so if you switch browsers you're always in sync,
>     as well as when you switch computers
> - Supports Opera, Google Chrome, Safari, iPhone, Opera Mini, via
>     Bookmarklets
> - Supports importing passwords from other password managers such as
>     Roboform, Keepass, PasswordSafe,
>     MyPasswordSafe, Sxipper,
>     TurboPasswords, PassPack, Firefox and
>     IE's built in password manager
> - Exporting your data always available in plugin and the website, even back
>     to Firefox.
> - In windows, helps you recover lost passwords stored on your computer
> - Capture passwords that other password managers will not capture
>     like those done in AJAX logins, and
>     multi-step logins like Bank Of
>     America, and frustrating sites like
>     ING bank using the 'Save All Entered
>     Data' feature.
> - Make moving to a new computer or using multiple computers much easier
> - Works with any platform that has Firefox
> - Mobile access at http://m.lastpass.com

Comment: wow, last pass is nice!!

Answer (score 0):

If this only occurs on certain websites, it may be that these websites specify that auto-complete is disabled. By default, Firefox obeys. There is, however, a [workaround](http://www.dailygyan.com/2008/08/force-firefox-to-remember-password-of.html), and a [Greasemonkey script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/why-doesnt-autocomplete-always-work-in-firefox/).

Comment: @sblair: It behaves like this in every site, it must be a setting of the browser bu i can't understand which is.

Comment: @Ivo How do you know it behaves like this on every site? It's not clear either way from the question...

Comment: He posten it as an answer, which I added as a comment here...